# How to change the layout of a page already created in the Lightning Community Builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, page-layout, community-builder

How can I change the Layout defined during page creation for an existing page? Assume the page is 2-column and you want to change it to 1-column or vice versa.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this is a gap in the Winter16 release. Some of the out-of-the-box pages, like Search, cannot be created with a different layout.

In Spring16, not only will you be able to do this, you will be able to change the layout after its creation using a new Change Layout feature.

In addition to this, you will be able to create your own layouts too (via creating a Lightning Components tagged in a special way). Note these features are in development so the Safe Harbor statement applies :)

Oh, and we will be including a bunch more layouts in addition to the two you have today.

Comment: Thanks, very cool! Is there a pilot for this?